# How do I make images appear in the beside blog post summaries?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I don't know if this is a WordPress question or a CSS question...

On my blog, in the list of post summaries, an image from a post appears beside the post's summary in the list of posts.

But that only happens with one post.

Other posts have images, but no thumbnail image appears in the list of post summaries.

I want to make it so that whenever I include an image or a video in a blog post, in the summary list, a thumbnail of the image appears. If I include more than one image in a blog post, then just one thumbnail appearing is ok.

Ideally, clicking the image would click into the blog post.

You can see the list of summaries at http://wordfruit.com/blog/

The one thumbnail is 11 posts from the top.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the theme files but I assume the one image is displaying because it is set as the "Post Thumbnail" or "Featured Image" on that particular post and that all other posts aren't using that feature.

The easy solution in that case would be to make sure you set any images you use in the post as the "Featured Image" as well.

If that isn't the case then you can modify your themes function file to grab the first image of any post and then modify your index.php file to include that image if it exists.

Here is a good tutorial on that:
http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it